# How to catch IIS specific errors irrespective of HTTP error code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am struggling to capture errors that are thrown by IIS itself. I would like to log an IIS error as well as the MVC errors.

I am using the latest version of `ASP.NET MVC 5` and running the website in `IIS 7.5` and debugging it locally. I am debugging though `Visual Studio 2013`.

I am trying to make use of the httpErrors tag in the web.config. I have starting to test 404 errros, but the same applies to all errors, 500, 403, etc. I just needed a starting point and decided to start with 404 errors.

I have the following configuration in my web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
<system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="Http404.html" responseMode="File" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

I tried the following to URLS:

- `www.mywebsite.com/foo/bar` - Error is caught and my breakpoint is hit in the Application_Error method
- `www.mywebsite.com/test.html` - This file doesn't exist. It is not caught in my Application_Error method so I can't log it. The correct error page is displayed, same as above

This is what I have in my Application_Error method:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I have minimal code here
    // First want to see if I can capture IIS errors here

    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
    HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;
}
```

How do I log an IIS error if it is not caught in the Application_Error method?

I have also tried this in an action method, it is also not caught in my Application_Error method, but correct error page is displayed:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to FilterConfig.cs inside App-Start folder.
Add the exception type and error page you want for the specific type of exception.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new LoggingExceptionFilter());
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute() { ExceptionType = typeof(HttpException), View = "HttpExceptionError" }, 2);

        }
```

Create a view with name `HttpExceptionError` in **SHARED folder**.

This will handle all the exceptions regarding http

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, IIS error handling is separate from ASP.NET, even in integrated pipeline mode. When IIS decides to return a non 200 status code, there should be no HttpException object created in ASP.NET to match that error, and therefore no way in ASP.NET to know that what IIS is going to do.

If you really want to log all error status, you can use C# to write an IIS extension to do so,

http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-a-module-using-net

Comment: Thanks will have a look at your link. I can log the ASP.NET errors and display a decent page for both ASP.NET and IIS errors. I just can't log the IIS error.